# How to play audio file (.wav) in browser instead of download it?

Tags: php, html, curl

According to CrazyCall [docs](https://developers.crazycall.com/#get-recording-that-belongs-to-call) I can download the recording of a call, so I tried to use PHP curl to get it:

```
<?php 

function records(){

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.crazycall.com/api/v1/calls/2/recording");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");

$headers = array();
$headers[] = "X-Api-Token: XCEFERlmvoj349jimXXXXXX";
$headers[] = "Account: WSXDEXXXXX.crazycall.com";
$headers[] = "Host: api.crazycall.com";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close ($ch);

return $result;

}

$sample = records();

header("Content-type: audio/wav");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=record.wav");
echo $sample;

?>
```

This works great, but now I want to play the audio file in browser instead of download it, I tried to use the audio tag like this:

```
<html><body>
<audio controls autoplay>
<source src="<?php echo $sample; ?>" type="audio/wav">
    Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
</body></html>
```

But it's not working, How can I fix it?

I'd like your help

Comment: you probably have to proxy it, unless you're OK with sharing your API token with browser visitors..

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with `Content-Disposition: attachment;`

That tells the browser to download the file.

Try changing `attachment` to `inline` as per https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition